# React js Material UI Error export 'LocalizationProvider' (imported as 'LocalizationProvider') was not found in '@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, material-ui, localization

I am new to React Js Material Ui. I am using latest version of MUI. I already installed mui/lab. When I trying to use DatePicker component, it throws an error like this.

Here is my code.

```
import * as React from 'react';
    import AdapterDateFns from '@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns';
    import LocalizationProvider from '@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider';
    import DatePicker from '@mui/lab/DatePicker';
    
    function User() {
  const [joiningDate, handleJoiningDate] = useState(new Date());
  
   return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <DatePicker
        value={joiningDate} onChange={ handleJoiningDate }   
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}

export default User;
```

When I save this code, I am getting error like this in my terminal.

`export 'LocalizationProvider' (imported as 'LocalizationProvider') was not found in '@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider`

https://mui.com/components/date-picker/#localization
I tried using the above link. But I cant able to rectify why this error came!!
Help me to came out of this error.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with similar issue. I solved it by trying with one of the following imports:

```js
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers-pro/LocalizationProvider';
// or
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
// or
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers-pro';
// or
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers';
```

In my case, the first one was not working, then I changed it by the second import and it worked perfectly.

Please, find [here](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/localization-provider/) the official MUI docs

**EDIT:**

Make sure also that you already installed `date picker` dependency. Follow [this link](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/getting-started/) to see how to install it according to your need.

If you use the actual version of MUI, please note that the date picker is now moving from `@mui/lab` to `@mui/x-date-pickers`. You need to migrate. Please follow the official instruction [here](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/migration-lab/) to do so.